# Reading process.env environment variables in AWS Lambda with Webpack 5 and Node

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, webpack-5

I'm bundling my Lambda Node project with WebPack. Calls to process.env are now coming back as `{}` despite there being variables set in the lambda.

I notice that WebPack 5 removed polyfils for a lot of Node functions. I've tried a long list of suggestions without success.

Can someone please provide assistance? Perhaps there's some AWS library which handles reading the environment that I'm might be removing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I was using this webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new NodePolyfillPlugin()
  ]
```

It was using browser.js which was setting `process.env = {}`