# Read Env variable of AWS Lambda in Nodejs webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, aws-lambda

Is there any way through which environment variables can be read in nodejs webpack?

While accessing

```
process.env
```

it returns null values.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with your webpack configuration. Have a look at [the answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325098/reading-process-env-environment-variables-in-aws-lambda-with-webpack-5-and-node) from a couple weeks ago.

Also, make sure that you don't define a function or variable named `process` in your code, as this would override the internal node.js `process` variable.